# How to redirect page after POST by fetch

Tags: javascript, html, fetch-api

I am sending register data to backend from client which works. I see my data in MongoDB, so it is ok. But after click "register" button I want to redirect to other page "/client/components/login/login.html" and redirection doesn't work. My `FORM` tag looks like that:

```
<form action="http://localhost:3000/register" method="POST">
    <div>
        <label for="register">Login</label>
        <input type="text" id="login" name="login" class="login" required>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" class="password" required>
    </div>    
    <div>
        <label for="password2">Repeat Password</label>
        <input type="password" id="password2" name="password2" class="password2" required>
    </div>
    <!-- <button type="submit" id="post-btn">Register</button> -->
    <input id="post-btn" type="submit" value="Register">       
</form>
```

This is my code where I POST data by `fetch`:

```
register = async () => {
    let url = 'http://localhost:3000/register';
    await fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        redirect: 'manual',
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        if (data.success) {
            window.location.href = data.url;
        } else {
            document.getElementById('message').textContent = data.message
            window.location.href = data.url;
        }
    })
    .catch(err => {
        document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = err
    });
};

document.getElementById('post-btn').addEventListener('click', register);
```

From backend I am receiving data like that:

> {"success":true,"message":"User has been created","url":"/client/components/login/login.html"}

I googled that redirection can be happened by `window.location.href` but it doesn't happen, after click "register" I am on 'http://localhost:3000/register' page. I don't even know how to `console.log(data)` from second `then` in `fetch` because after click "register" I am landing immediately on 'http://localhost:3000/register'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you click the submit button, it triggers the JS but while `fetch` is asynchronously making an HTTP request **the form submits normally**. This triggers navigation and **cancels the JS**.

You need to prevent the default behaviour of the click on the submit button.

```
register = async (clickEvent) => {
    clickEvent.preventDefault();
```

---

NB: Generally should should be binding to the submit event on the form and not the click event of the submit button.

Comment: I treied this before and doesn't work, but thanks.

Comment: @misugi — All else being equal, this will solve the problem. Maybe you have other problems (such as `document.getElementById('post-btn')` returning `null` which would give you an error in the console) in addition to the one that is clearly visible in your question.

Comment: document.getElementById('post-btn') is not null it is what it should be :) After addind preventDefault() and then after I click "register" button nothing happend, even my data are not send to backend.

Comment: And the error is: "Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: data is not defined
    at HTMLInputElement.register", maybe I will try to handle this by myself, thanks :)

Comment: IT'S WORKING ! ! !

Answer (score -1):

Try to do so

```
register = async() => {
   window.location.href = `${website_url}/client/components/login/login.html`
   // your code
}
```

Comment: That would redirect **before** making the POST request (except it will be cancelled by the regular form submission so it will have no effect just like the existing code).